# A Poisson process is memoryless

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Suppose we have the Poisson process $\{N(t), t\geq 0\}$. I want to prove the following identity:
$$
\mathbb{P}(N(s+t) = k | N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0 \leq u \leq s\}) = \mathbb{P}(N(s+t) = k | N(s) = j)
$$
which seems intuitively clear. The events after time $s$ only depent on what happens between time $s$ and $t+s$, it does not depent on the events beforehand. But trying to prove this, I came along the following reasoning which seems to disprove the statement:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(N(s+t) = k | N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0 \leq u \leq s\})\\[1mm]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(N(s+t) = k, N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}{\mathbb{P}(N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}\\[1mm]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(N(s+t) - N(s) = k-j, N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}{\mathbb{P}(N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}\\[1mm]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(N(s+t) - N(s) = k-j)\cdot \mathbb{P}(N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}{\mathbb{P}(N(s) = j, \{N(u), 0\leq u\leq s\})}\\[1mm]
&= \mathbb{P}(N(s+t) - N(s) = k-j)\\[1mm]
&> \mathbb{P}(N(s+t) = k, N(s) = j).
\end{align*}
The third equality holds because $N(s+t) - N(s)$ is independent of $\{N(u), 0 \leq u \leq s\}$, by definition of a Poisson process. The last inequality holds because if $N(s+t) = k$ and $N(s) = j$, then $N(s+t) - N(s) = k-j$, but the reverse is not necessarily true (so $ \{N(s+t) =k \cap N(s) = j\}\subset \{N(s+t) - N(s) = k-j\} $). Is there a mistake in this argument, or is a Poisson process not memoryless?

Comment: I thought only the exponential distribution was memory less.

Comment: The Poisson process isn't memoryless, it is Markov. Roughly speaking, ``memoryless" means that the past doesn't matter whereas "Markov" means that only the immediate past matters.

Comment: You're right. The assignment called it 'memoryless', but 'Markov' indeed fits better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is good up to your inequality. 
You have correctly shown that
$$
P(N(s+t)=k | N(s)=j, \{N(u), 0<u<s\}) = P(N(s+t)-N(s)=k-j).
$$

Now start with only $P(N(s+t)=k | N(s)=j)$, without the $\{N(u), 0<u<s\}$ and show that it is also equal to $P(N(s+t)-N(s)=k-j)$.

Then you are done!

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Though this raises the question why my inequality is false. Could you give an explanation for this?

Comment: You're welcome. As for your inequality, it is true but "uninteresting". You are trying to prove that $P(N(s+t)=k|N(s)=j, \{N(u), 0< u < s\}) = P(N(s+t)=k|N(s)=j)$ not that $P(N(s+t)=k|N(s)=j, \{N(u), 0< u < s\}) = P(N(s+t)=k,N(s)=j)$. (Note that $P(N(s+t)=k|N(s)=j)>P(N(s+t)=k,N(s)=j)$.)